# Title_save_pre - Simple problem that u know for sure

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I have two custom post type. Then I need to use **title_save_pre** to post title prior to saving it in the database. I need to use this filter just for one custom post type.

This is my function:

```
<?php
function muda_titulo() {
global $post;
$type = get_post_type($post->ID);
if ($type== 'event') {
$title = $post->post_excerpt;
$day= get_the_time('l, d F, Y');
return $title.' - '.$day;

} else if ($type == 'post') {
// do nothing 
}
}
add_filter ('title_save_pre','muda_titulo');
?>
```

On custom post type 'event' it works fine, but on custom post type 'post' the title changed to a white space.

Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. Filter's take a value and returns it afterwards.

```
  <?php
    function muda_titulo($title) {
    global $post;
    $type = get_post_type($post->ID);
    if ($type== 'event') {
    $title = $post->post_excerpt;
    $day= get_the_time('l, d F, Y');
    return $title.' - '.$day;

    } else if ($type == 'post') {
       return $title;
    }
    }
    add_filter ('title_save_pre','muda_titulo');
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I used some of your code here to help me fix a problem I was having trying to convert a Taxonomy Term into a post title for a specific post.  However it is not effecting the permalink when it applies the filter.  Any help you could give would be great -- and thanks for the code as well, gave ya an upvote!  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/copy-a-taxonomy-term-into-the-post-title-for-a-certain-custom-post-type