# Set Custom Post Type title to the Post's Date

Tags: custom-post-types, date-time, title

I have a custom post type, called 'status' and I have disabled 'title' in the post type. Right now it's setting all posts to have the title "Auto Draft". I want to set up a way to set the title to be the post's date. I think I should be using 'wp_insert_post_data". Right now I am using the following code but it is not working:

```
function status_title_filter( $data , $postarr )
{

if ($postarr['post_type'] == 'status'){
    $date = $data['post_date'];
    $data['post_title'] = $date;
}
return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'status_title_filter' , '99' );
```

Thanks in advance for solving my simple problem. I'm a sort of novice when it comes to this kind of things.

Comment: Hi.. I think you might be able to use the code found here to solve your problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7829/title-save-pre-simple-problem-that-u-know-for-sure   I was having a problem similar to yours (trying to set the post title to a specific taxonomy term).  I am still having some trouble with mine though, as it sets the post-title but doesn't update the permalink.  My question is posted here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/copy-a-taxonomy-term-into-the-post-title-for-a-certain-custom-post-type   Good Luck!

Answer (score 5):

Despite what the Codex says, $postarr doesn't always get passed in, so you should just use $data. $data isn't a meaningful variable name, though, so I prefer $cleanPost. I'd also try removing the priority on the filter, since it's not usually necessary. It's also a good idea to set the slug (`post_name`) in addition to the title, and to avoid running the code on auto-drafts and trash/untrash operations. See if this works instead:

```
function status_title_filter( $cleanPost )
{
    if( $cleanPost['post_type'] == 'status' && $cleanPost['post_status'] != 'auto-draft' && $_GET['action'] != 'trash' && $_GET['action'] != 'untrash' )
        $cleanPost['post_title'] = $cleanPost['post_name'] = $cleanPost['post_date'];

    return $cleanPost;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'status_title_filter' );
```

---

**Update**: I think the reason you don't see $postarr is because by default action callbacks only accept one parameter. If you want more then you have to specify that in the hook, like `add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_callback_function', 10, 2)`. That would set the priority to 10 and the number of arguments to 2.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that does that - [datetitle](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/06/30/datetitle-a-wordpress-plugin-for-automatic-post-titles/). Maybe you could look at the code there and get an idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late, but you can set the title to the postdate right before you create the post.

```
$postarr['title'] = current_time('mysql');
$postarr['post_type'] = 'myposttype';
wp_insert_post($postarr);
```

HTH