# Check for update vs new post on save_post action

Tags: save-post, wp-update-post

Is it possible within the save_post action to determine whether it's a new post being created or an existing post being update?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. See my comment below @moraleida's answer. Why do you need to know if it's a new post or being updated? There may be a work-around or an alternative approach.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since WordPress version 3.7. - IIRC - the `save_post` hook - more information about the hook and its usage at [Code Reference: `save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) and [Codex: `save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) - has a third parameter `$update` which can be used to determine just that.

> @param     int               $post_ID     Post ID.
>   @param     WP_Post     $post          Post object.
>   @param     bool            $update      Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.

---

*Note:*

`$update` is not always `true` – you can see and test it yourself with below code. It is not well documented though, possibly far from optimally named, and hence creates misleading expectations. Below code can be used for some debugging, play around with when to intercept code execution, because otherwise you won't see the information/messages. I think, the culprit in deceptive behavior is the handling of revisions and auto saves – which could be disabled, but I don't recommend it, and haven't tested it. Not sure if this warrants a [Trac Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/), so I didn't open one, if you think so, please follow the link and do it yourself. Aside from that, as stated in the comments, if you have a specific problem, post a new question.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'debug_save_post_update', 10, 3 );
function debug_save_post_update( $ID, $post, $update ) {

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $post ); echo '<br>';
  echo '$update == ';
  echo $update ? 'true' : 'false';

  //conditions
  if( ! $update && $post->post_status == "auto-draft" ) {
    // applies to new post
    echo ' && $post->post_status == "auto-draft"';
    //die();
  } else if ( ! $update ) {
    // applies basically to the (auto saved) revision 
    //die();
  } else {
    // applies to updating a published post
    // when there is a revision, which is normally the case, 
    // standard behavior of WordPress, then it is considered 
    // an update, which is where the confusion sets in
    // there are other methods, like checking time or post status
    // depending on your use case it might be more appropriate 
    // to use one of those alternatives 
    //die();
  }

  echo '</pre>';
  //die();
}
```

Comment: The `$update` parameter is ALWAYS true even when it is a new post.  So this parameter is useless.  Not sure if it ever worked at all, but it sure as hell isn't working the way it's documented in the latest version of wordpress 4.8.

Comment: @SolomonClosson If you take a look at `wp_publish_post`, then yes. But that isn't true for its usage in `wp_insert_post`. I've written a debug function, I add it to the answer.

Comment: @SolomonClosson If you have a actual concrete problem, please ask a new question. Take a look at the revisions for the debug function an explanation.

Comment: The `save_post` hook has a 3rd parameter that is always set to TRUE, so not sure what this has to do with other hooks, not speaking about other hooks.  I'm talking about the hook in your answer.  This is incorrect.

Comment: @SolomonClosson As I said the hook is occurring two times:
[`wp_insert_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3510), [`wp_publish_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3619). The latter is only future posts, there `$update` is set to be always `true`. Otherwise, in regards to `wp_insert_post()`, `$update` is not always `true`.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but hey, why not, @Nicolai, what you are saying is what one would expect to happen, but I can't get $update to be false even when I hook to 'wp_insert_post'. No matter where I hook it, it' always true. I don't understand why this isn't fixed.

Comment: Guys, just an info. The hook is fired on restoring and deleting a post.

Answer (score 14):

The way I perform this check (within a hooked function) is to compare the post date and modified date (in GMT for standardisation)

```
function check_new_vs_update( $post_id ){
    $myPost        = get_post($post_id);
    $post_created  = new DateTime( $myPost->post_date_gmt );
    $post_modified = new DateTime( $myPost->post_modified_gmt );
    $diff          = $created->diff( $modified );
    $seconds_difference = ((($diff->y * 365.25 + $diff->m * 30 + $diff->d) * 24 + $diff->h) * 60 + $diff->i)*60 + $diff->s;

    if( $seconds_difference <= 1 ){
        // New post
    }else{
        // Updated post
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'check_new_vs_update' );
```

This works because even at creation the post has a 'modified' date attached to it, which is exactly the same as the 'created' date, but we allow a variance of 1 second either way in case a second ticks over during the creation of the post.

Comment: Sometimes the `post_date_gmt` is `2019-03-12 01:31:30` and the `post_modified_gmt` is `2019-03-12 01:31:31`. :(

Comment: @HeYifei何一非 good point, if the processing begins at the end of a given second, this could happen. I've updated my answer, thanks

Comment: Guys, just an info. The hook is fired on restoring and deleting a post.

Comment: Good to know @melvin, thanks

Comment: I can't believe that it as to be so complicated. Wordpress never cease to amaze me.

Comment: To be fair to them, they have literally millions of users and it's an open-source project. Unfortunately they can't include every feature and this is probably not one of the most-used. In recent years things like improving the editor and security has been prioritised and that's good! I mean even jQuery is only being brought up to date now! Until the current version it has been running 1.x!

Answer (score 6):

I ended up just checking for the existence of a custom value prior to setting it.  That way, if it's a newly created post the custom value would not yet exist.

```
function attributes_save_postdata($post_id) {
  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
  if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_attributes_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) return;
  if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) return;
  } else {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return;
  }
  $termid = get_post_meta($post_id, '_termid', true);
  if ($termid != '') {
    // it's a new record
    $termid = 'update';
  } else {
    // it's an existing record
  }
  update_post_meta($post_id, '_termid', $termid);
}
add_action('save_post', 'attributes_save_postdata');
```

Comment: For this to work, do you have to first create the custom field using add_post_meta?

Comment: Per the Codex: [update_post_meta] may be used in place of add_post_meta() function.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Comment: This might fail, if posts were created before the code hook gets enabled via a plugin activation. Older posts dont have the meta set, hence the first update for them will be considered as new.

Comment: @VasuChawla so in that case maybe its more reliable to check the existence `isset()` (for example) of that specific meta term instead of whether its true or false. As a third condition. (`if`, `elseif`, ...`else`)

Answer (score 3):

Example to ialocin answer with "update" paremeter:

```
function save_func($ID, $post,$update) {

   if($update == false) {
     // do something if its first time publish
   } else {
     // Do something if its update
   }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_func', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: A better way to structure this would be either putting the update block first, allowing to just do `if($update)` or keeping the new block first but using `if( ! $update )`. The latter will get OP into better practice and is preferred over your method by WordPress coding standards in cases like the [ternary operator](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#ternary-operator)

Answer (score 2):

I have just encountered the `save_post` about new and update. After reading the source code to understand the flow. I found that the following method might be useful. Since it is not yet mentioned before. See if it is useful to anyone. (The test is Core 5.3.3)

The Post creation flow is approximately:

1. After pressing Add New (Post)
2. $post = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type, true ); will be called where
3. get_default_post_to_edit() receive argument $create_in_db = true
4. so wp_insert_post() is immediately being called, `auto-draft` post is being created, even it is not saved, every time clicking `Add New`, an `auto-draft` is created
5. $update is always true for Publish. So when Publish a new post, it is true.

By comparing the $_POST object for new post and update post or republish post, the prominent difference is value `_wp_http_referer`, the new post is `/wp-admin/post-new.php`

Assumption: assumed the post is published/added from UI. If it is done by other mechanism, custom code, the checking is needed to adjust.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'test_save_post_check', 0, 3 );
function test_save_post_check( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    // other tests + this
    // checking the 'post-new' position from the '_wp_http_referer'
    if( strpos( wp_get_raw_referer(), 'post-new' ) > 0 ) {
        // new
    } else {
        // update
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a functional code that worked and tested by me i used in my website also it solve the two following problem associated with save_post action :

1. problem to check between ubdate or insert
2. problem of twice insert by save_post action

   ```
   function save_annonces_callback($post_ID, $post, $update){

           $post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);

           if ( $post_type === 'annonces' ){

               //this to preventtwice insert by save_post action :)
               if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
                   return;
               } else {

                   //check if new post so insert
                   if( strpos( wp_get_raw_referer(), 'post-new' ) > 0 ){

                       //perform insert

                   }else{

                       //perform update
                   }

               }

           }
       }add_action('save_post','save_annonces_callback', 10, 3);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pre_post_update action hook for the update code and save_post for the new post code. It works before a post is updated.

Comment: `save_post` hook is fired **both** when a post is created and updated (after WordPress has saved it to the database). `pre_post_update` is fired when a post is updated, but *prior* to the post being updated - this can be important.

Answer (score 1):

As Darshan Thanki hinted (and Stephen Harris further elaborated), you can use `pre_post_update` to your advantage.

```
global $___new_post;
$___new_post = true;

add_action(
  'pre_post_update',
  function() {
    global $___new_post;
    $___new_post = false;
  },
  0
);

function is_new_post() {
  global $___new_post;
  return $___new_post;
}
```

The reason why I used globals is because `function is_new_post() use ( &$new_post )` is not valid in PHP (shocking...) so pulling in that variable into the function scope doesn't work -- hence the global.

Note that this can really only reliably be used within/after the `save_post` event (which is usually sufficient, at least for what we're doing with it).

Answer (score 0):

When save_post is triggered, all information about that post is already available, so in theory you could use

```
function f4553265_check_post() {

    if (!get_posts($post_id)) {
    // if this is a new post get_posts($post_id) should return null
    } else {
    // $post_id already exists on the database
    }
}
add_action('save_post','f4553265_check_post');
```

this is untested, though. =)

Comment: By the time you get to `save_post` the post itself would have already been saved to database - so `get_posts` would return the current post.

Comment: True, just checked it in the Codex. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: This does not work with `get_posts` but it works with `get_post`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that uses a built-in function and no addition to the database would involve `get_post_status()`.

```
$post_status = get_post_status();
if ( $post_status != 'draft' ) {
    //draft
} else { 
    //not a draft: can be published, pending, etc. 
}
```

Note however that it might not be appropriate if you plan to later set the status back to "draft" – your instructions would be repeated the next time you will update the post.
Depending on the context, you might want to consider the various strings that can be returned by `get_post_status()` to build a more appropriate scenario.

See Codex for [get_post_status()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_status) and [Post Status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status)

> Possible values are:
>
> - 'publish' - A published post or page
> - 'pending' - post is pending review
> - 'draft' - a post in draft status
> - 'auto-draft' - a newly created post, with no content
> - 'future' - a post to publish in the future
> - 'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in
> - 'inherit' - a revision. see get_children.
> - 'trash' - post is in trashbin. added with Version 2.9.

Comment: I don't think this does what was asked for. If I create a new post and then hit 'Publish', `save_post()` is executed for the first time, but during that execution `get_post_status()` already returns 'publish' and not 'draft', even though it is only in the process of being published.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `$update` param is useless, this is the fastest way I tested:

```php
function wpse48678_check_is_post_new($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (false !== strpos($_POST['_wp_http_referer'], 'post-new.php')) {
        return true; // Or do something else.
    } else {
        return false; // Or do something else.
    }
}
add_action('save_post_{$post_type}', 'wpse48678_check_is_post_new', 10, 3);
```