# title_save_pre on post publish

Tags: custom-post-types, title

I'm trying to build the title of a custom post using the values within post custom fields. The problem is that using `title_save_pre` only executes when I update the post, not when I create it.

When I create the post I get the title : **(no title)**
If I edit and save I get the right title.

I need to get the right title in backend.

This is my code:

```
function update_phone_title($title) {

global $post;

$type = get_post_type($post->ID);

if ( 'phone' == $type) {
    $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'manufacturer', TRUE);
    $title .= ' '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'model', TRUE);
    $title .= ' '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'memory', TRUE);
} 

return $title;
}
add_filter ('title_save_pre', 'update_phone_title');
```

FIXED using wp_insert_post_data .I did it with this code:

```
function filter_handler( $data , $postarr )
{
  global $post;
  $id = $post->ID;

  if('phone' == $data['post_type'] && isset($data['post_type']))
    if($id) {
        $title = $_POST['fields']['field_4fd2897fc0bfe']. ' ' . $_POST['fields']['field_4fd2897fc2328'] . ' ' .$_POST['fields']['field_4fd2897fc273a'];
        $data['post_title'] = $title;
    }
  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_handler' , '99', 2 );
```

Comment: I would use the `save_post` hook instead. You should also perform some nonce and permission checks. `wp_insert_post_data` (like `save_post`) is triggered on occasions when the post is created or edited outside of the 'edit post' screen, where your data in `$_POST['fields']` is not present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter `title_save_pre` runs before the post is written to the database, and also before any of its post meta is saved to the database. So `get_post_meta` at this point will be blank for the first run, and always return 'old' data.

To correct this you'll want to hook into `save_post` and update the post from there. `save_post` runs after the post has been saved to the database, and the in-built 'custom fields' have been saved.

To do this you can use [`wp_update_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post). However, you'll need to be careful:

> When executed by an action hooked into save_post (e.g. a custom metabox), wp_update_post() has the potential to create an infinite loop. This happens because (1) wp_update_post() results in save_post being fired and (2) save_post is called twice when revisions are enabled (first when creating the revision, then when updating the original post—resulting in the creation of endless revisions).
>
> If you must update a post from code called by save_post, make sure to verify the post_type is not set to 'revision' and that the $post object does indeed need to be updated.

One way round this is to remove the `save_post` callback from the hook inside the callback, as demonstrated [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops).

Comment: I added my fix to the initial question.