# Add the custom post term to the custom post title

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, title

what I need is this: add a term from a custom post to the post's title. Like this: Custom Post title - term

Right now I have:

```
$terms_of_post = strip_tags (get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'my-custom-term', '','', '', '' ));

elseif ( is_single() ) { single_post_title(); {echo ' ('; echo $terms_of_post;  echo ')';} ; }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, but it seems it should.

I have found [Copy a Taxonomy Term into the Post Title for a certain Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22537/copy-a-taxonomy-term-into-the-post-title-for-a-certain-custom-post-type?rq=1), which could be 90% of the answer, but instead of replacing the post title with the taxonomy title, I need to add it to the title.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (based on your unfinished PHP code)

```
if ( is_single() ) { 
    $terms_of_post = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID() , 'my-custom-term', '',', ', '', '' );
    $terms_of_post = strip_tags ( $terms_of_post );
    single_post_title(); 
    if( $terms_of_post ){
        echo ' (' . $terms_of_post . ')';
    }
}
```

to get this format:

```
Title (term1, term2, term3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My connection was down and I could not test this. But I can confirm it works.

Comment: ok, great to hear that, cheers.