# DOING_AUTOSAVE function in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types

Can anybody please explain in simple words (layman's terms), what this function actually does.

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}
```

I am learning to code custom post types and I found this function for saving the content of meta boxes.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10):

That conditional logic first checkes if the constant `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is defined by using the PHP function `defined('SOME_CONSTANT_NAME')`.

Then the logic checks to see if the state/value of the constant `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is `true`, that's the second part of the conditional right after the `&&` (and).

So if `DOING_AUTOSAVE` has been defined in the request lifecycle and the state/value of `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is `true` then we `return` which is a means of aborting the logic that is to follow beneath the conditional.

`DOING_AUTOSAVE` only gets defined and set as true in the `wp-admin/includes/post.php` file within the `wp_autosave()` function.

Of course it may be defined elsewhere customly...

- Learn more about `wp_auto_save()` here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_autosave/
- Learn more about `defined()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php