# How to set custom post type as post title to avoid 'Auto Draft'

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a mixture of Advanced custom fields plugin and Custom post type UI to give my users some extra functionality. The problem I have is that I have serup a testimonials menu and in the list view all new posts appear as `Auto Draft`. Is there anyway I can make the field slug `client_name` act as the post title for the list view?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to have the users fill out the title field and use it as the client name? [Woothemes' testimonials plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonials-by-woothemes/) does this. If that's not an option, you can look into adding a filter on title_save_pre. Haven't used it myself but here are examples:

- From StackExchange: [Title_save_pre - Simple problem that u know for sure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7829/title-save-pre-simple-problem-that-u-know-for-sure)
- From WP Support Forums: [Generating and setting a custom post title](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/generating-and-setting-a-custom-post-title)